# get address ip automatically in appsettings.json

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2022

I have a connection for a database and everytime IP adress changes, is there a way to get it automatically ? and to put it automatically in appsetting.json:

`"DefaultConnectionString": "Server=tcp:xxxxxx,1435;Database=xxxxxx;User=sa;Password=xxxxxx;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=true"`

Comment: Could you please tell me when this IP will changes?  Normally, the connection for the sql server is registered as the signleton. If you want to get the IP address and then use it for connection, I suggest you could consider writing it inside your codes and you could firstly get it and then use it to build the sql connection class.

Comment: It may be a peculiar academic exercise - but it's a very bad idea. if IP changes (and even if it doesn't), then you should be using server name, and maintain the mapping of name to IP through DNS tools